# Matplotlib place y axis on the right with flipped label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have the y axis on the right hand side of my plot, but also have the label facing the correct direction. There's many answers that explain the first part, which can be done as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
ax.set_ylabel("RHS")
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following:
[image]

But the issue here is the yaxis label on the right hand side is facing outwards, and ideally I would like it to face inwards, something like the following:

[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following kwargs to your [set_ylabel](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html) call:

```
ax.set_ylabel("RHS",rotation=-90,labelpad=15)
```

which gives the intended output:

[image: output]

If you want to modify label after it has been set, alternatively you can do something like:

```
yl = ax.set_ylabel("RHS")
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
yl.set_rotation(50)
# do some other stuff
```

then don't forget to call `plt.draw()` to make it effective. You may want to have a look at [matplotlib text](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) instance properties.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. If you happen to know, is there a way of modifying the rotation of the ylabel of an axes after the ylabel has been set, without resetting the ylabel? Something along the lines of `ax.ylabel.rotation = -90`?